# Building on a docker image that sets user to an unprivileged user

Tags: docker

```
https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile
```

sets USER to jenkins.

When I try to say `FROM jenkins`, and then do things like `apt-get`, I get permission denied.

Can I set the USER back to root, install some things, and then put it back to jenkins?

I tried the obvious, and it didn't work.

```
ARG user=root
ARG group=wheel
ARG uid=0
ARG gid=0
```

I still lack permission for subsequent commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
USER root
```

not

```
ARG user=root
```

is the solution here.